# NSPredicate for to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have object `Movie`, that have to-many relationship `events` Each Event, has property `date`
I need create fetchedResultController with such Movies that have event in concrete day

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForEntertainments:(Class)className date:(NSDate *)date
{
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass(className)];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy/MM/dd";
NSDate *startDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [NSDateComponents new];
oneDay.day = 1;
NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:startDate options:0];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(events, $s, ($s.date >= %@ AND $s.date < %@)).@count > 0", startDate, endDate];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"objectId" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
return fetchResultsController;
}
```

I want create predicate that will return me Movies, that have Event with current day date

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working like you want? Can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: Post a piece of code to test (and the test data, as that is a pain to set up, that one's on you!)

Comment: Have you verified that `startDate` and `endDate` contain the expected values?

Comment: Yes all dates correct

Comment: And what is the problem? No results, wrong results, crash ... ? You have to provide more information.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a typo - `$s.date >= %@ AND $s.date < %@` is this
correct? That is and impossible case, please check this.
Edit:
I have mistaken. It is correct